# A way to install Nulled directadmin on ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, hosting

Is there any way to install a Nulled Directadmin on Ubuntu 12.10? I want to learn how to use the Directadmin before i buy it, So i thought of installing a Nulled Directadmin first. Anyone know if it is possible to install it and if so, Then how to install it?

Comment: http://www.directadmin.com/ubuntu.shtml read this.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily ask DirectAdmin staff for a trial license. Nulling a commercial product is a criminal offense.